Why Google_Service_Drive type is undefined
Please someone help me with this.
Why the Google_Service_Drive is undefined? I Has installed the google/apiclient and do the configuration on .env file but it still says its undefined.
I've been tryng to update the google/apiclient and composer but its says its already the latest version. i've trying to clear the config cache too buts its no use and i did 'dd(class_exists('Google_Client'), class_exists('Google_Service_Drive'));' to check the class is exist or no but nothing happend, maybe its because I dont know how to use it cause i'm never done this before.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Please add some more details to your question. What have you tried to do? What version are you using? And so on

I believe that format is an older format and the newer version uses namespaces, for example
require ("path_to_google_vendor/autoload.php")
//$client is \Google\Client
$service=new \Google\Service\Drive($client);

//Create a folder in root of google drive
$file=new \Google\Service\Drive();
$file->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');
$folder = $service->files->create($file);

A lot of old examples would use the _ version : Google_Service_Drive. For the entire google API you can replace the _ with a \ to get the namespaced version
